# how can one declare a word or number from a txt file into string

Tags: java, string

I'm writing a program to keep track of customer exchanges. I'm trying to take the number in a txt file of one of the customers and declaring the number as a string in order to use it .example add it to another number.I've tried doing different things like reading it as the last line but I get the error cannot find the symbol. please help I'm pretty new to java and trying to learn as much as I can.

Thank you here's the code I've tried.

```
  FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(acc+".txt");
  BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));

  String strLine = null, tmp;

  while ((tmp = br.readLine()) != null) {
     strLine = tmp;
  }
  String lastLine = strLine;
```

So I tried using the last line but it says cannot find the symbol and I've no idea what to do

this is the error: `cannot find symbol int we=lastline-o; ^`

Comment: Can you [edit] your question and post the entire text of the _cannot find symbol_ error that you are getting. If you also have a stack trace, then please post that as well.

Comment: Java is case-sensitive. `lastline` is **not** the same as `lastLine`.

Comment: thank you I changed lastline to lastLine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read the file in this approach, keep the last line from last step with the current newline

```
  FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(acc+".txt");
  BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));

  String currentLine, lastLine, tmp;

  while ((tmp = br.readLine()) != null) {
     // read new line
     currentLine = tmp;

     // do your logic
     lastLine + currentLine;

     // update last line for next iteratino
     lastLine = currentLine;
  }
```